# In Yocto, adb logcat is not executed

Tags: adb, yocto, logcat

I added android-tools_5.1.1.r37.bb on orangepi.
And adb shell,push,pull,etc is working well but adb logcat,adb reboot, adb remount is not working.

When executing adb logcat, below is output:

```
$ adb logcat
/bin/sh: line 1: exec: logcat: not found
```

What should I check for this issue?

Comment: `adb logcat` is just a shortcut (with special argument passing) for the command `adb shell logcat` which means it executes the `logcat` command on your phone. If the Android installation misses this command (or the command is not in PATH) then you get the error message you got.